# Creating c++ namespace like snippets in subime text

Tags: c++, sublimetext2, code-snippets

I am looking for a way to create some c++ namespace like snippet in sublime text2 which should behave like this:

assuming we have a namespace called "fu" which contains "vector","Point,"Mat". I create snippets with following tabtriggers:

```
<tabTrigger>fu::vector</tabTrigger>
<tabTrigger>fu::Point</tabTrigger>
<tabTrigger>fu::Mat</tabTrigger>
```

When I now type "fu" the selection box with all 3 snippets appears (which is perfect), but as soon as I type "::" they all disappear.Why is that? Even when I type "fu::vecto" there is no selection for the snippet. It seams that the double point escapes all snippets triggers.

I really need the behavior when I type "::" which should me show all definition in the specific namespace.

Is that somehow possible?
Thank you in advance for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Text 2 considers the `:` character to be a word separator, so to Sublime Text, typing a `:` is just the same as typing a space to separate words. Ergo, it cuts off autocompletion.

You can make `:`s in snippets work in the way you want them to by adding this line to your user preferences file (`Preferences -> Settings - User`. Make sure to fix commas if you need to):

```
"word_separators": "./\\()\"'-,.;<>~!@#$%^&*|+=[]{}`~?",
```

That's just the `word_separators` value from the default settings file, but with the `:` taken out.

If you only want Sublime Text to ignore `:` in C++, add the line to your C++ preferences file instead (`Open a C++ file -> Preferences -> Settings - More -> Syntax Specific - User`).